# Cxx.jl converting between Julia Complex and std::complex

Tags: c++, julia

I'm currently using Cxx to allow Julia code to interact with a C++ library. Part of what I want to do is to efficiently pass collections (typically vectors) of complex data in both directions. That is, I'd like something along the lines of:

```
cv = [1 + 2im, 0 - 1im, ..., 1 + 0im]
cxxv = convert(cxxt"std::vector<std::complex<int>>", cv)
new_cv = icxx"process_complex_vector($cxxv);"
# do some stuff with new_cv
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that Cxx.jl is not well maintained and that if you're serious about wrapping a C++ lib, you should use [CxxWrap.jl](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/CxxWrap.jl).  I tried to use Cxx to wrap a library and gave up.  Your  results may vary.

That said, it may be that Keno would respond better on the Julia [slack](https://julialang.slack.com/).

Comment: I like CxxWrap and have used it, but find the Julia side a little awkward. Definitely worth keeping in mind, though.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to access julialang.slack.com from work, so I'll have to wait a bit before pursuing your second suggestion.